# Nested For, Do while, Do until, If-else loop

Tags: excel, vba, nested

My goal is to find work duration in time.

Store final CLOCKIN time in a variable START (different time stamp belong to CLOCKIN).

The person left for lunch (CLOCKOUT) and came back (CLOCKIN), store the lunch time difference in variable LUNCH.

Finally, the person left the office for the day, store the final CLOCKOUT time in variable EXIT (as different time stamps are for CLOCKOUT).

In the end, code should give me work duration in office LUNCH-START = FINAL1 and EXIT-LUNCH=FINAL2, answer = FINAL1+FINAL2 in hours.

I want to repeat above exercise for different dates.

Data Description: I have a table of 6 columns (date, time, name, doorName, EntryType). In the EntryType column, I have criteria CLOCKIN and CLOCKOUT. CLOCKIN mean the individual entered the office door. As you see in data table, there are  multiple times for data value 'CLOCKIN'  which means the individual swipes card at different doors. As he swipes his card through each door, a timestamp is generated which is shown in column 'time'.

For example, Driver, Craig swiped card at door 1 at  4:47:29AM. He swiped card through door 2 at  4:50:09AM and finally swiped card trough door 3 at  4:50:28AM. Finally, he is in office. Now, he CLOCKOUT at 11:43:10AM which means he left the office for lunch. He came back to office at 11:55:47AM. At the end of the day, he left the office for good while swiping through doors at 3:00:35PM and 3:02:58PM.

I want to calculate how many hours Driver,Craig was in the office. Simply, he came to office at 4:47:29 am, left for lunch for 15 minutes (from 11:43:10AM to 11:55:47AM). He left office finally at 3:02:58PM. Therefore, he was in the office around 10 hours. How do I find it using VBA?

I wrote VBA code and I was able to pull times separately but could not figure our next step of calculating final time.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim x As Integer
Dim lrow As Long
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
x = 1
    With Range("F:F")
        For x = 1 To lrow
            If Range("F" & x) = "INBOUND" Then
                Range("F" & x).Select
                Range("h" & x).Value = CDate(Range("b" & x))
                ElseIf Range("F" & x) = "OUTBOUND" Then
                Range("F" & x).Select
                Range("I" & x).Value = CDate(Range("b" & x))
            End If
            Next

    End With
End Sub

Sub workduration()
    'need to subtract first entry time from last entry time until it is punched out i.e unitl row where exit time shown
    'check until exit column in blank
    Dim a As Integer
    a = 1
        For a = 1 To 8
        If IsEmpty(Range("i" & a)) = True Then
                     
            Cells(a, 10).Value = "=MOD(cells(a+1,8).value - cells((a,8).value ,1)*24"
           
        End If
        Next
              

End Sub
```

the image shows the data table

[image]

I wrote another VBA code it but also, it did not work. It is as follow

```
Sub times()
Dim x, m As Integer 'shows column # containing desired word
Dim y, n As Integer 'shows row# containing desired word
Dim var, var1, var2 As Variant
Dim lrow As Integer
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Integer
For Each Cells In Range("F:F")
       Set rfind = .Find(what:="INBOUND", Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
         If Not rfind Is Nothing Then
            'MsgBox rfind.Column
            'MsgBox rfind.Row
            x = rfind.Row
            y = rfind.Column
        Cells(x, y).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Select
          var1 = (ActiveCell.Value)
          var3 = CDate(var1)
        Selection.Font.Color = vbRed

        End If
       Set cfind = .Find(what:="OUTBOUND", Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
       If Not cfind Is Nothing Then
            'MsgBox cfind.Column
            'MsgBox cfind.Row
            n = cfind.Column
            m = cfind.Row
        Cells(m, n).Select
        Selection.Offset(0, -3).Select
        var2 = ActiveCell.Value
        var4 = CDate(var2)
        Selection.Font.Color = vbGreen
        End If
        Range("H2").Formula = "=CDate(var4) - CDate(var3)"
        answer = DateDiff("h", var3, var4)
        'Range("H2").Formula = "=mod(var4-var2,1)*24"
    End With
      Range("h" & i).Value = answer
Next i
        'Range("J1").Formula = "=sum(range("h1":"H100"))"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please describe "did not work". _How_ did it not work? What is the expected vs. actual result? (Also, `if`/`else` is not a loop.)

Comment: It gave me individual times for criteria 'clock in' and clock out (SUB "MACRO1()") worked. I want to calculate how long driver, craig was in the office so I want to subtract clockIn time from final clockout time and also take out lunch time (SUB work duration() did not work). Also, I am not sure how to set for different dates. My end goal of the data is the find how long a person was in office for different dates clockout-clockin. There are different timestamps for CLOCKOUT and CLOCKIN which is making hard to calculate work duration in office.

Comment: what my vision is when a person CLOCKIN, store the time value in a variable START, and find final CLOCKIN time for different timestamps belonging to CLOCKIN. As he CLOCKOUT for lunch and CLOCKIN back from lunch, store the difference in time in LUNCH variable. When he finally CLOCKOUT. , store the difference in final CLOCKOUT time in EXIT variable LUNCH-START = FINAL1and EXIT-LUNCH=FINAL2 , answer = FINAL1+FINAL2  in hours.

Comment: did anyone find solution how to do it?